# Failed to load control 'imagelist' from mscomctl.ocx on Windows server 2003

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vb6

I am working on windows server 2003. The program written in VB was working fine previously.

But now it starts to show error message :

```
failed to load control 'imagelist' from mscomctl.ocx. Your version of
mscomctl.ocx may be outdated. [...]
```

[image]

How can i check if `mscomctl` is registred or not and also what version i am using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the mscomctl.ocx file from [microsoft download center](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=25437D98-51D0-41C1-BB14-64662F5F62FE), then learn on how to [register an activeX control manually!](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2746232)

Answer (score 1):

Unregister and register *mscomctl.ocx*:

```
cd /d C:\Windows\SysWOW64
regsvr32 /u /s mscomctl.ocx
regsvr32 /s mscomctl.ocx
```

Explanation: In most cases isn't OCX file rewritten by an older version, but the older version is placed in some directory by an incorrect setup program and registered in this new place. So it is sufficient to unregister & register again. *regsvr32.exe* takes the right one from *C:\Windows\SysWOW64* folder.

Answer (score 0):

Also, maybe not the most probable cause, but could save some time: **disk space**.

We had this issue on our VM, we got this message and we figured out we had no byte left on the C: drive. The issue didn't occur after some cleaning.